# CompletedCheckpoint failure to load file missing causes entire cluster to fail

Tags: apache-flink

We are using Apache Flink jobs with checkpoints enabled on Kubernetes cluster.
We are seeing from time to time the following error:

```
/flink/ha/default/completedCheckpoint6180310b69c1 (No such file or directory)
and 
Could not retrieve checkpoint 2728 from state handle under checkpointID-0000000000000002728. This indicates that the retrieved state handle is broken. Try cleaning the state handle store.
```

also in the stack:

```
Failed to initialize high-availability completed checkpoint store
eventually:
JobMaster for job aa524fd45d98dc7bb0b1be7798a87415 failed.
and Fatal error occurred in the cluster entrypoint.
```

the entire flink pod is killed and restarted but same goes on again and again only clearing the config-maps help.

how can we tell flink not to fail in case of job recovery failure we have a mechanism for recreating the job through our application.